# Using Dynamic Programming to find number of valid combinations for a given number of parantheses

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Problem Statement : Given the number of parantheses, find the total number of distinct combinations such that the parantheses are balanced. There is only one type of paranthesis involved - '(',')'

I am looking for a dynamic programming based solution for this

Comment: More info is needed. Do we have several types of parentheses like [, (, {? Must the parentheses be balanced?

Comment: `F(0) = 1`, `F(n) = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} F(j)*F(n-1-j)`

Comment: As amit said, catalan number is the way, and this number can be computed using DP (if you want)

Comment: I am specifically looking for dynamic programming based solution

Comment: @Aadith What is the range for number of parentheses? It is the most important thing if you want to talk about **DP**

Comment: following amit: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~wdtseng/icpc/notes/dp1.pdf

Comment: @PhamTrung The input would be the total number of parantheses to be used to form the combinations. If the input is 4, it would be required to count all valid combinations of four '('s and four '('s. Could you please clarify what you mean by range here?